# Nginx, reverse proxy and caching only some of the routes

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a RESTful API running in the UK but somehow it's so slow for AU users. So what I would like to do, put an nginx proxy on a AU server and cache some of the routes for 1, 10 and 60 mins and don't cache the rest at all.

I am not sure if that's achievable with nginx but here's what I did;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name proxycache.domain.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/reverse.log upstreamlog;

    proxy_ignore_headers    Set-Cookie;
    proxy_hide_header       Set-Cookie;

    proxy_ignore_headers    Cache-Control;
    proxy_ignore_headers    Vary;
    proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Redirect;
    proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Expires;
    proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Limit-Rate;
    proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Buffering;
    proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Charset;
    proxy_ignore_headers    Expires;

    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host data.domain.com;

    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_cache             STATIC;
    proxy_cache_key         $host$uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_cache_min_uses    1;

    location /api/a {
        proxy_pass  http://data.domain.com/api/a;
        proxy_cache_valid   200 301 302 1m;
        break;
    }

    location /api/b {
        proxy_pass  http://data.domain.com/api/b;
        proxy_cache_valid   200 301 302 60m;
        break;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://data.domain.com/;
        proxy_cache_valid   200 301 302 0s;
        break;
    }


}
```

It's working if I request for `/api/a` or `/api/b` or any other URL but if I send a request for something like `/api/a/some_other_var` it's again, falling to last location instead the first one. So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know, that it fails to last location?

Comment: @AlexeyTen I am watching the access logs on the API side + it doesn't return the right results, so it falling to the last.

Comment: From `data.domain.com` these locations are indistinguishable.

Comment: Is it real locations? May be you have some other problem?